# Error while trying to run PHP script from Python

Tags: php, python

I have WAMP installed on my Windows PC. I have a python script that has the following code, which is supposed to run my php script located in www of wamp (C:\wamp64\www)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("php C:\wamp64\www\index.php")
```

I also tried the below but it did not work also

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.31\php.exe C:\wamp64\www\index.php")
```

However, when I run the python code from `IPython` I get the following error. (see image)

[image: Error in IPython]

Comment: try `subprocess.call("php C:/wamp64/www/index.php")` - \ is an escape character

Comment: Try passing raw string to the function `subprocess.call(r"php C:\wamp64\www\index.php")` and if possible, state the full path to the `php` binary

Comment: @rndus2r both suggestions did not work

Comment: try to add the full path for php

Comment: `subprocess.call("C:/wamp64/bin/php/yourphpversion C:/wamp64/www/index.php")`

Comment: `subprocess.call("C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.31 C:/wamp64/www/index.php")` try this

Comment: @mwweb that did it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add full path of PHP

```
subprocess.call("C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.31 C:/wamp64/www/index.php")
```

Or Add php to environment variables. Open CMD and type:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.31
```